# Cruise Control Executing Python Script

Tags: python, xml, ant, cruisecontrol, build-script

I have a project that uses a single .py file to build and zip everything. How can this be called successfully in Cruise Control? I have tried the following for a default Ant build script:

```
<project name="x" default="build">
<target name="build">
    <exec executable="python2.7.2" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="C:\build\trunk\build.py" />
        <arg value="$(label)" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

However, Cruise control comes back with "cannot run program 'python 2.7.2' the system cannot find the file specified.

This is a real newbie question, but could someone point me in the right direction for getting CC to execute a .py script? I can't find a single good resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simply, python2.7.2 is not part of you "PATH" and is not located in the same directory where your ant script is. Therefore it cannot be found. Either put python exe to your path before starting Cruisecontrol server ( that's how we do it ) or use an absolute path to it ( not recommended ).

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I mistyped the executable name!